# How to subscribe Apache Kafka topic and stream data to Hive table

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How to subscribe Apache Kafka topic and stream topic data to Hive table?
The Kafka topic will be updated in real-time.

Comment: Adding more details to questions subject and rephrasing body.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is with Kafka Connect and the [HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html). [Here's a quickstart](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart) showing you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the KafkaConnect's HDFS connector.

All the configuration properties and common examples could be found at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/configuration_options.html#hive

For a sample configuration you can look at the configuration posted in the question :
[kafka connect - ExtractTopic transformation with hdfs sink connector throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367856/kafka-connect-extracttopic-transformation-with-hdfs-sink-connector-throws-null)

Answer (score -1):

You could use Kafka connect sink using the HDFS connector specified above and create an external table using Hive for that particular HDFS location.

Comment: Confluent's HDFS Connect already has Hive integration, so building the external table isn't necessary. Also, that won't dynamically update partitions if you do it this way